# When writing/editing an answer or a question - how do I insert an image through a web link / URL?

Tags: discussion

When writing/editing an answer or a question and adding an image through the "image-button":

Didn't there used to be an option to insert an image through a web link / URL (e.g. `https://meta.stackexchange.com/image123.png`)? Right now I only get the "drag&drop option" or the "open file" dialogue which can not handle web addresses. Is it still possible to use a web link or do I have to download the image locally and then upload it again?

I think there used to be a link you could click which opened a window where you can put/paste the URL of the image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Is it still possible to use a web link?

Yes. In Firefox at least just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> (or click on the image icon), then paste the URL directly using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> (on Windows):

[image]

Which will insert:

[image]

Comment: ah, ok, when you "paste" the URL (or any text) the address field for the URL appears automatically. I think there used to be a link you could click to make the field appear. Do you know why it has been removed?

Comment: @Albin It's part of [Editor improvements for images and links](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576) which is part of [Rollout of responsive design site themes - Tracking post](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/314979)

Comment: Thanks, although I support the afford for responsive design, this particular change is real bad usability (when you are working with desktop/laptop)... ah, well...

Comment: @Albin I find it ok, but then I'm used to the shortcuts :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, once you know the shorcut it's fine... finding the shortcut without any hint is a little problematic, especially for new users (who don't know it's possible at all)...

Comment: I wish they would stop "improving" the sites.  A lot of the "improvements" hurt usability.  In this case, how would any user know how to use this interface (contains no guidance)?  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @fixer1234 [Can't upload image from URL anymore](//meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1041458)

Comment: Doesn't work at all on Safari, Mojave. Works on Chrome.

Comment: This change is ridiculous, tbh. It's counter-intuitive. And stupid. Ugh.

Comment: Meh - this didn't work... then it did for a couple of days... now it doesn't again. Mojave 10.14.2, Safari.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it manually.

Images are almost like normal links, except for the leading exclamation mark.

```
![Description](direct image link)
```

So

```
![xkcd](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/beverages.png)
```

becomes

[image: xkcd]

Comment: Might be an option for some pictures, but this way an external image stays external and is lost if the website or the url to the image changes.

Comment: Good point. I use this mainly for images that I have already uploaded to imgur.